# IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite redirection is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

In IIS 8.5 - Need to URL (framnaes) - https://www.manpowergroup.no/framnaes  to  new 
web site - https://framnes-installasjon.no.
I have tried many  pattern and condition. But not working.Could you please help me to fix it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Learn how to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! In my previous POst/Answere I am not able to post whole Rule tag.
Anyways here this regular expression "/[^/]+/sub-dir-name" worked for me to find out the specific directory in url and then redirect to another website.

Thanks